# how can i get a float value from this string using?? C programing

Tags: c, string, function, extract

I'm learning C and I'm trying to extract a float value from a string, it must be in this kind of format. But when I enter a number in my string it only returns an int, can someone help me? thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

float daNum(void);
int main (void)
{
  float value = 0;

printf("please enter a value:");
value =  daNum();

printf("your value is:%.3f \n", value);

return 0;
}


float daNum(void)
{
char store[121] = {0};    
float numba = 0;
int const kInvalInput = -5;

fgets (store, 121, stdin); 

if( sscanf (store, "%f", &numba) != 1)
{
numba = kInvalInput;
}

return numba;
}
```

Comment: works for me: https://ideone.com/i2yCbG

Comment: What did you type as a value?  Did you use dot or comma as the decimal point?

Comment: `3,14` is two integers separated by comma; `3.14` is a floating-point value (possibly depending on *locale*, but your program is using the "C" locale anyway).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i used a dot

Comment: Using a dot is good, but it’s only part of what I asked.  What did you type (and what did you get printed)?

Comment: Im testing it with visual studio and i get this 

please enter a value:1000.111111
your value is:1000.11108
(I edited the %.5f in the printf and added #pragma warning(disable: 4996) before the function definition)

When i try to test it https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler in this website i get a full int :/ @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @user3121023 its looks thats the answer to my problem but i havent seen pointers in class and i dont really understand it (ive tried) is this the only way to work around it? ty for your comment

Comment: Given that you’re using `float` rather than `double`, the `1000.11108` result is pretty much as good as can be expected.  It isn’t an integer value.  So I’m not clear what the problem is.  It would also be a good idea to edit the “what I typed and what I got” information into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float strtof (const char* str, char** endptr);`.

[Full documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/)